# JSON Padding With PHP

Tags: php, json, jsonp

Please can anyone assist I'm trying to get my JSON data displayed on my html5 localhost page,

I'm still new to JSON

I get the following returned  but no data is loading on the page.

http://www.hostname/getCheck.php?callback?&callback=jQuery110205560797746881064_1392215061343&_=1392215061344

Please if anyone can assist.

Below is my php script

`` `mysql_select_db($database_xxx, $xxx);
    $rsfet = "SELECT * FROM cs_tracking ";
    $fet = mysql_query($rsfet, $xxx) or die(mysql_error());
    $json = array();
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($fet)){
    $json[] = $r;
    } ``

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo $callback ='('.json_encode($json).')';`
```

and my javascript to display the table data

```
` 
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
    url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/getCheck.php?callback=?',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: true,
    success: function(data){
               $.each(data,function(i,photo){
                 var tblRow =""
    +""+data.CS_Track_Child+""
    +""+data.CS_Track_Date+""
    +""+data.Tracking_Status+""
    +""+data.CS_Tracking_ID+""
    +"" ;
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });
     },    

     });
    });`
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$callback` variable is not magically declared in your script (at least, it shouldn't be); you can access the value via `$_GET['callback']` but make sure to sanitize its value:

```
if (isset($_GET['callback']) && preg_match('/[A-Z]\w*/i', $_GET['callback']) {
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    printf('%s(%s);', $_GET['callback'], json_encode($json));
}
```

Comment: I tried the code and my php script is generating the JSON, my table displays undefined for each value.

Answer (score 0):

You have two GET parameter of `callback` one is valid but empty and second is invalid.

http://www.hostname/getCheck.php?callback?&callback=jQuery110205560797746881064_1392215061343&_=1392215061344

```
url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/getCheck.php?callback=?',
```

So remove your parameter and try with this:

```
url: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/getCheck.php',
```

Comment: i have found the problem;

Comment: I didn't call the correct data inside the table. i used data.CS_Track_Child instead of item.CS_Track_Child, i also changed (i,photo) to (i,item) Thank You for all the help.